# WebClient Adding Handlers to Mono with ExchangeFilterFunctions

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am wondering if adding functionality to the Mono that I return from an ExchangeFilterFunction will be applied to the final Mono that gets returned. Basically I am wanting to clean up some of my client code by move some of the concerns out of the client class and into ExchangeFilterFunctions that I can add to the client, but my case is a bit different than a single call.

Basically I have something similar to the below code:

```
    Flux.fromIterable(uris)
        .parallel()
        .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
        .flatMap(uri -> webClient.get()
            .uri(uri)
            .headers(headers -> headers.addAll(httpHeaders))
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(
                status -> status.is4xxClientError() || status.is5xxServerError(),
                response -> response.bodyToMono(String.class)
                    .map(body -> new MyCustomException(body, response.statusCode())))
            .bodyToMono(MyResponse.class)
            .map(x -> Tuple.of(x, null))                
            .onErrorMap(ReadTimeoutException.class, th ->
                new MyCustomException(ErrorResponseBuilder.buildError(th), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)))
        .doOnEach(this::log)
        .sequential();
```

My question is can I move out some of this logic for example the error handling and probably retry logic and additional logging to ExchangeFilterFunctions instead and if I do that will they  still get applied when put into the Flux?

Also in the ExchangeFilterFunctions how would I be able to access the SubscriberContext because there is data in the context we need when logging like the unique id of the request that gets used for tracing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error handling logic could definitely be separated out, this Baeldung [article](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) is very useful to help with this

On a further note I would recommend refactoring your code so as to not have any nested maps/flatmaps. This will make your code more readable and will probably lead you to understand which parts should be extracted out. This [article](https://medium.com/@nikeshshetty/5-common-mistakes-of-webflux-novices-f8eda0cd6291) covers this well

Comment: Thank you very much.